# Groovy view in Eclipse (and some in Java) lost numerous key bindings and functions

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I recently upgraded my Eclipse Kepler instance to Luna (STS 3.6.4).  I've been editing both Groovy and Java files for a couple of weeks now, along with some Gradle scripts.  In the last day or so something weird happened to the Groovy view.  I appeared to have lost most of my key bindings.  I also use the Emacs+ plugin (I've used this for a very long time), which makes it easier for me to view my existing bindings.

I haven't made an exhaustive list of the bindings I've lost, but here's a short list:

Ctrl+L: go-to-line
Ctrl+Right: next-word
Ctrl+o: quick-outline

I'm sure there are many more.  The first two work fine in my Java view.

The third one is the first one that I noticed I was missing, and I had gone into the Keys in preferences and made some changes to try to fix this.  Now I can't get even get "Quick outline" to work in the Java view, although when I press Ctrl+o, I see the little popup in the bottom right that shows the bindings associated with the prefix I've entered so far, which lists "Ctrl+o "Quick Outline".

The Eclipse log shows a lot of errors, which I'm including here:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the key bindings from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' extension point

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui', id='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.inplace.show'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.boot.BootLaunchShortcut.run'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.boot.BootLaunchShortcut.debug'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.refresh.all'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.inlineMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.inlineMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.rename'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.rename'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.groovyScriptLaunchShortcut.run'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.groovyScriptLaunchShortcut.debug'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.convertToMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:06.807

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.convertToClosure'



!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:10.631

!MESSAGE The POM for org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.8.2.v20130124-134944 is missing, no dependency information available



!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the key bindings from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' extension point

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui', id='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.inplace.show'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.boot.BootLaunchShortcut.run'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.boot.BootLaunchShortcut.debug'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.refresh.all'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.inlineMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.inlineMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.rename'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.rename'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.groovyScriptLaunchShortcut.run'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.groovyScriptLaunchShortcut.debug'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.convertToMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-03 21:46:34.911

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.convertToClosure'



!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the key bindings from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' extension point

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui', id='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.inplace.show'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.boot.BootLaunchShortcut.run'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.boot.BootLaunchShortcut.debug'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui', id='org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.refresh.all'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.inlineMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.inlineMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.rename'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.command.rename'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.groovyScriptLaunchShortcut.run'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.groovyScriptLaunchShortcut.debug'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.convertToMethod'

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 06:52:38.642

!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui', id='org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.convertToClosure'

!SESSION 2015-04-04 07:12:41.356 -----------------------------------------------

eclipse.buildId=3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44

java.version=1.7.0_51

java.vendor=Oracle Corporation

BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide

Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide



!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.core 4 0 2015-04-04 07:12:44.376

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

!STACK 0

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.core [417]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
   org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [426]
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)



!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util 4 0 2015-04-04 07:12:44.381

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

!STACK 0

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util [419]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.2.0.201501270702"
   org.eclipse.fx.core [417]
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
      org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [426]
        Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)



!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser 4 0 2015-04-04 07:12:46.334

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

!STACK 0

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser [987]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="0.9.0"
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="1.2.0.201501270702"
   org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util [419]
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.2.0.201501270702"
      org.eclipse.fx.core [417]
        Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
        Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
          -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
         org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [426]
           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)



!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted 4 0 2015-04-04 07:12:46.340

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

!STACK 0

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted [994]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser; bundle-version="3.6.4.201503050833-RELEASE"; singleton:="true"
   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser [987]
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="0.9.0"
       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="1.2.0.201501270702"
      org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util [419]
        Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
          -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.2.0.201501270702"
         org.eclipse.fx.core [417]
           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
           Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
             -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
            org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [426]
              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)



!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-04-04 07:12:51.216

!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be one.proxy.att.com.



!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-04-04 07:12:51.220

!MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.



!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-04-04 07:12:51.220

!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be one.proxy.att.com.



!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-04-04 07:12:51.221

!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.



!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-04-04 07:12:51.222

!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be one.proxy.att.com.



!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-04-04 07:12:51.222

!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.



!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 4 2015-04-04 07:13:03.412

!MESSAGE Error in inferencing engine for YangGenerateTask.groovy

!STACK 0

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1342)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ImmutableClassNode.enableWriteProtection(ImmutableClassNode.java:128)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ImmutableClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(ImmutableClassNode.java:120)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:986)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.CategoryTypeLookup.lookupType(CategoryTypeLookup.java:63)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.lookupExpressionType(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:2047)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.handleSimpleExpression(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:2015)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.visitConstantExpression(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:1477)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstantExpression.visit(ConstantExpression.java:79)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.visitMethodCallExpression(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:1649)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:64)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.visitField(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:723)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.visitJDT(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:520)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.visitJDT(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:408)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.visitCompilationUnit(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:352)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.editor.highlighting.GatherSemanticReferences.findSemanticHighlightingReferences(GatherSemanticReferences.java:52)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.editor.highlighting.GroovySemanticReconciler.reconciled(GroovySemanticReconciler.java:153)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.reconciled(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1664)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconciled(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:212)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconciled(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:164)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:144)

    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.initialProcess(MonoReconciler.java:105)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler.initialProcess(JavaReconciler.java:406)

    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:173)



!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2015-04-04 07:13:04.900

!MESSAGE Caught exception in FS.readPipe()



!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 07:13:08.739

!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.



!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui 2 0 2015-04-04 07:13:13.846

!MESSAGE Restoring of editor state failed

!STACK 0

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.ui.state.EditorStateParticipant.restoreEditors_e_3_8_2(EditorStateParticipant.java:419)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.ui.state.EditorStateParticipant.restoreEditors(EditorStateParticipant.java:370)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.ui.state.EditorStateParticipant.restoreState(EditorStateParticipant.java:128)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.ui.state.ContextStateManager$3.run(ContextStateManager.java:114)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.ui.state.ContextStateManager$3.run(ContextStateManager.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core.CommonListenerList$1.run(CommonListenerList.java:93)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core.CommonListenerList.notify(CommonListenerList.java:85)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.ui.state.ContextStateManager.restoreState(ContextStateManager.java:110)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.tasks.ui.ContextStatePersistenceHandler.activated(ContextStatePersistenceHandler.java:62)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.tasks.ui.ContextTasksStartupHandler$ContextActivationListener.contextChanged(ContextTasksStartupHandler.java:113)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.core.InteractionContextManager$6.run(InteractionContextManager.java:714)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.core.InteractionContextManager.internalActivateContext(InteractionContextManager.java:705)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.core.InteractionContextManager.activateContext(InteractionContextManager.java:186)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.context.tasks.ui.TaskActivityMonitor$2.taskActivated(TaskActivityMonitor.java:75)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.core.TaskActivityManager.activateTask(TaskActivityManager.java:481)

    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin$TasksUiInitializationJob.runInUIThread(TasksUiPlugin.java:380)

    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)

    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)

    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)

    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)

    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)

    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)

    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)

    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)

    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)

    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Caused by: org.eclipse.ui.MultiPartInitException: Factory org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ClassFileEditorInputFactory returned null from createElement for editor id=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ClassFileEditor name=null

    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditors(WorkbenchPage.java:4798)

    ... 48 more
```

**Update**:

Someone had pointed out I should be running this with Java8, which I forgot to set up.  That was a good idea, but it made no difference for this problem. The following is a stacktrace from the log that likely resulted from me manually running the "quick-outline" function:

```
!MESSAGE Code assist internal error

!STACK 0

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1457)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ImmutableClassNode.enableWriteProtection(ImmutableClassNode.java:128)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ImmutableClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(ImmutableClassNode.java:120)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:986)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.CategoryTypeLookup.lookupType(CategoryTypeLookup.java:63)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.lookupExpressionType(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:2047)
```

Comment: Some of your plugins (org.eclipse.fx.core for example) are failing to start because they require Java 1.8

Comment: Great idea. That was one detail I forgot when setting up this new environment.  The bad news: no effective change. I'll update with some more information.

Comment: If it matters, I filed a JIRA for this at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1833 . Note that my Kepler instance is configured as close to exactly the same as possible, and I don't have this symptom. Also note that I see similar behavior in the Java view in the Luna instance (described in the JIRA ticket).

Comment: If it matters, my self-answer for this was to give up on the STS installation.  I installed a fresh Luna distro and got back to a functIonal environment.